# Malicious Google Drive Links

Tags: authentication, spam, url-redirection, url, google-apps

Curious about a new form of spam I've noticed in my inbox. Someone seems to be using my email address to fill-out forms on sites, so that I receive the bounce back message. In this message there is a link to a google drive.

What are the dangers of visiting said link? I would assume nothing can come of it as long as I don't authenticate or allow the what I assume to be requested access to my google account.

Mostly, want to visit it to be able to report the drive to google, seeing as most documentation I find about reporting requires one to actually be on the drive one wants to report.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we can’t analyze your malware from out here. Sounds like that link may be pretty sketchy, but we can’t say one way or the other. If you’re super curious to know more, one pretty common technique for analyzing malware is to download and execute it in a VM. If you do that, obviously be careful to configure everything properly and keep a firm sandbox. Good luck!

Comment: At first I assumed it would take me to some Google site Sheet/Document and request all kinds of permissions from my Google account to be able to send mail for me and read contact list etc. 

But didn't check the url close enough when I posted. https://drive.google.com/file/d/#################################/preview is the pattern for the url, so could it be a file that can execute from GDrives preview mode?

Was mostly looking for a way to report these to Google without accessing them. Assuming it's not trivial to create Google accounts all the time I was hoping to bother the spammer.

Comment: @Sindri Looks like just another link to the file to me. Unless you give us the actual file or a link to it, we have no way of telling whether or not your file is malicious. It's a good rule of thumb to not actually click on a suspicious link in your everyday browser. You can try it in a sandboxed environment or with `curl`.